# Data from a WebSocket into a Table with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json, object, display

my Script is reading Data given from a WebSocket and my goal is, to save the Data from the Websocket in a Table (HTML). This is what my Function looks like, as you can see im reading the Data from an Object, and im trying to display each Object in my HTML Table.

```
function websocketPush(item){
    let t_item = {}
    for ( let key in properties){
        t_item[key] = resolve(properties[key],item);
    }
    t_item["id"] = id;
    id++;
    //data.push(t_item);
    //data = data.slice(-30);
    table.addData([t_item],true);
}
```

But instead of logging each item in the Table, its just logging 1 by 1 and keeps resetting the old ones.
So basically I want all the logged filed in the table and not just the newest one. I think my problem is the "id++" but I just dont know any better...

Any Help is appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Comment: You have to put your code inside the loop, since it is out for loop it will only add once.

Comment: Yeah now it looks a bit better, but it still only uses 4 columns and resets the ones which are already logged.. so confusing.. but thanks anyways!

Comment: `t_item` needs to be outside `websocketPush`, every time you receive item, you are initializing `t_item = {}`.